# Building Java multiplayer server game - difference between sockets and webservice

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm building a multiplayer card game using Flex on the client side and Java on the server side and I wanted to know if I must sockets and the accept method in order to connect users to the server for in order for them to join a game room or create one or to chat.
In the past I've learned how to build a game server which both sides are JAVA and connection was in sockets but now days the client side will be in FLEX which has few ways to connect to a Java server (XML,SOAP,BLAZEDS(AMF)) and I find it hard to understand how to write the Java server in order to do all the features of a game server , especially managing the rooms and sending data back to the users.
In the sockets way, when a user was connecting to the server and he had opened a room, this room was opened on a thread and who ever was joined that room then he was connected to the same thread and sending the messages to the right place was easy, so the problem is understanding how to do the same using SOAP or BLAZEDS.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using raw sockets gives you the benefit of control. Control of your protocol format ( how your message data is structured). And because of this you can tweak your messaging to be more secure, or faster, or more robust, depending on your application requirements. All that control comes at the cost of complexity and maintenance. Because you get to say exactly what you want to send and how you want to send it you need to write and debug alot more code. Another issue with raw socket communication is that it has a significantly greater chance of being blocked by firewalls.

Using web services removes some of the complexity of deciding on a message format (with that being it's main benefit). You don't have to worry about things like byte endian-ness, string encodings, or data conversions (as much). As such web services really excel at data communications amongst heterogeneous clients and servers where inter-operability is key. The cost being that it's relatively complicated to serialize/deseserialize, and as such, slower than binary messaging formats. Web services are good to use when you have to communicate with client applications that you have little control of (not really your case). Web services are traditionally tunneled through HTTP, so there is an additional advantage in being able to worry less about a firewall blocking access to your game.

BlazeDS attempts to bridge both worlds - it gives you some of the robust features of web services (fallback communication options, firewall interoperability etc), but uses it's own binary format for serialization/ deserialization. This gives it some of the speed of using raw sockets without a lot of the downsides. I think it's a great candidate to explore, but if you find yourself needing more speed then raw sockets would be worth messing around with.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, How can I implement what I need in the server side using blazeDS since FLEX supports BlazeDS. All the tutorials on the net explains how to get DATAGRID but that doesn't help me. I need a tutorial about how to build a server that can handle clients messages and send the messages back, handle chat servers, game rooms , database etc..

Comment: @Alon - all I can suggest is work through as many of the tutorials as you can. Then get your thoughts together on how you think your server should work, and put together a prototype. If you have particular problems while doing this then come back and post follow up question(s) on SO. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please make your questions concise, it is difficult to know what is being asked for.

If you ask the difference between socket and webservice, sockets are used to manage the basic networking communications. Over them, you can receive/send bytes in whatever format / protocol you chose to.

SOAP / Webservices is just one of such formats, its advantage is that it is a standard way of encoding messages so you can easily write code that connects to your service in most platforms, and those messages are human-readable. The main disavantage is performance, both in bandwith and processing power (specially to parse it at the receiving end).

If you are starting, I would advise designing a format related to the application you are using to simplify things.

Comment: thanks for your answer, In the past I have learned to create a multiplayer java game that both sides are on java, thus we used sockets. Nowdays I want to make a nice GUI with FLEX which supports spring,hibernate,blazeDS, XML,SOAP etc... what's hard for me to understand is how do I build the server side to manage the players playing the game, managing rooms, chat server, db access etc without using sockets ? do I need to use sockets even if I use SOAP, or any other new way ?

Comment: all communication goes through socket. If you encode/decode "by hand" your own SOAP messages, you will need to use a socket to send/receive it. Most of the time it is useful to use a library like axis and/or a container like Tomcat that already manage the sockets for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RED5](http://www.red5.org/) and remoteSharedObjects. Using this tech, you can essentially put you "game" object in a remote shared object, and all the clients will have the same object with real time updates. Then on top of that you can use AMF (the protocol behind BlazeDS) for your less dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are the programmatic interface to [OSI Level 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) Transport Layer. Everybody uses them, ie Webservices is a Level 7 Application Layer interface that hides the lower levels.

If you need real-time **bidirectional** data exchange between your client and server you're better off managing your own TCP sockets. Flex still supports sockets.